# How can i resolve this error: ssh root @[hostname] ssh: Could not resolve hostname root: Name or service not known

Tags: ssh, server, backend, hostname

```
ssh root @[hostname] 
ssh: Could not resolve hostname root: Name or service not known
```

This is the error i'm receiving when i try to connect to the server. I'm using WSL Ubuntu on windows, i don't know why i'm recieving this error please help me. I'm using digital ocean and I'm on IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a space between root and @ it thinks that root is the host you want to connect to.  Eliminate that space.

Comment: yes you are right i just deleted the space and  i've been able to login to my server now thank you so very much

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue